# editar template de excel en react native

Tags: excel, react-native

Tengo un template prearmado de excel y necesito completarlo con informacion recopilada en un formulario de react native.
Descargue la librería xlsx y pude lograr llenar la planilla de excel pero pierdo los estilos del template.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo una planilla de excel con un formato y tengo una app de react native con un formulario...necesito que cuando se complete el formulario, llene la planilla de excel con esos datos en las celdas que yo le indique, y luego enviar ese archivo al backend

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisar [ask], saludos.